# thingworx select multiple properties

Tags: thingworx

I want to select two properties using thingworx, I was able to select one property (first name) using this request:

```
https://example.com/Thingworx/Things/navigation/Properties/firstname?appKey=xxx
```

now I want to select first name and last name (both in the same use case : navigation)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look onto services instead of Properties, for instance Service "GetNamedPropertyValues" or "GetNamedProperties" and pass as parameter the list of properties values to recover

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer ThingWorx REST API Cheat Sheet on

```
https://community.ptc.com/t5/ThingWorx-Developers/ThingWorx-REST-API-Cheat-Sheet/td-p/532533
```

Basically you can send a GET Request to

`https://<host>:<port>/Thingworx/Things/<thingName>/Properties/*?appKey=<appKey>`

to fetch all properties related to that thing. You can also update multiple Properties using a PUT request.